# iOS compile error: No visible @interface for 'setLocationManager' declares the selector

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode6

I am currently completing a Ray Wenderlich iOS tutorial over #Augmented Reality , and I came to a problem concerning the setLocationManger not being found in the MainViewController interface?? How can I fix it?

Which I don't understand because I thought this was included in the class of CoreLocation/Corelocation.h.

```
#import "MainViewController.h"
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
@interface MainViewController () <CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapViewPointer;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocationManager *locationManagerPointer;

@end

@implementation MainViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Roll Tide

    [self setLocationManager:[[CLLocationManager alloc] init]];
    [_locationManagerPointer setDelegate:self];
    [_locationManagerPointer setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters];
    [_locationManagerPointer startUpdatingLocation];
```

Comment: Provide full error explanation and point on lane, in which error occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocationManager *locationManagerPointer;`

Either rename `locationManagerPointer` to `locationManager` or call the setter as

`[self setLocationManagerPointer:[[CLLocationManager alloc] init]];`

When you declare a property setters and getters are automatically created.

If you have a property declaration as `@property NSString *userName`, a setter with method `setUserName` and getter `userName` will be created. You can access them as `[self setUserName:@"fooBar"]` and `[self userName]`. Reason for your error is that your property name differs to that of you setter.